# JSON-SERVER cors missing origin 403

Tags: cors, vuejs3, json-server

So I have this `json-server` setup in my `vue3` project and everything just works fine until this one endpoint `/leads` throwing me this error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://mydomain/leads. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 403.
```

I'm not sure why because the other endpoint which is `/inquiries` with the same code, a **copy-pasted** code is working even without the `cors` npm package.

But I installed it anyway just to make sure cors is setup for all my enpoints. But I'm still getting the same error.

So I would run the `json-server` like this:

```
json-server db.json --watch --middlewares cors.js
```

Here's my `cors.js` file:

```
const jsonServer = require('json-server')
    
// Import the library:
const cors = require('cors')

const server = jsonServer.create()       
        
// Then use it before your routes are set up:
server.use(cors())

module.exports = cors()
```

Here's both `/leads` and `/inquiries` endpoint with the same request headers:

[image]